# Get array of both matches and non-matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

What I want to do is split up a string into an array of multiple contiguous substrings, alternating between matches and non-matches of a given regular expression.

Like this:

```
[nonmatch, match, nonmatch, match...]
```

For example, with the right regex (the actual expression being not important here),

```
"I [went to the doctor] today to [eat some] food"
```

might become:

```
["I ", "[went to the doctor]", " today to ", "[eat some]", " food"]
```

I need to do this because I need to take out some parts of a string temporarily, do some stuff to the rest of the string, and then insert the previous parts back where they were to make the string whole again (by simply combining the entire array into a string).

All I can find from searching are people who want to either get rid of some of the string (e.g. the [] in the example above) or join some non-matches and matches together, like:

```
["I ", "[went to the doctor] today to ", "[eat some] food"]
```

Comment: Why don't you think the regex used wasn't important ? Without it you question seems unclear to me.

Comment: This is still vague!!!

Comment: The regex is some regex that selects groups of characters between square brackets. I would like to build an array consisting of both the matches and non-matches for that regex, in the correct order.

Comment: How many levels there could be? Is this a possible string: `I [went [to] the] doctor`???

Comment: You can split your string and do what you want with the parts, but you can also use `String.prototype.replace` with a function as replacement parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `split` for that, passing it a regular expression that has a capture group (i.e. parentheses). Then this delimiting part will also be included in the resulting array:

```js
var s = "I [went to the doctor] today to [eat some] food"
var result = s.split(/(\[.*?\])/);
console.log(result);
```

The matches will always be at the odd indexes of the resulting array.

Comment: I think for the given description this is more than a correct answer

Comment: It's exactly what I was going to post.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, actually. Thank you a lot. It even ensures matches are always at odd indices, which is brilliant and very precisely what I was after.

Comment: Thanks for this - was something I was after as well.